# How to calculate CPU memory usage of fit_generator in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a network using Keras and I've got a problem with `fit_generator` and excessive use of memory.

I currently have 128GB of RAM and my dataset occupies 20 GB (compressed). I load the compressed dataset in RAM and then use a `Sequence` generator to uncompress batches of data to feed the network. Each of my samples is 100x100x100 pixels stored as `float32`, I'm using a `batch_size` of 64, `queue_size` of 5 and 27 workers with `multiprocessing=True`. In theory, I should have a total of 100*100*100  *4  *64  *5  *27 =~ 35 GB. However, when I run my script, it gets killed by the queuing system because of excessive memory usage:

```
slurmstepd: error: Job XXXX exceeded memory limit (1192359452 > 131072000), being killed
```

I've even tried to use a `max_queue_size` as little as 2, and the process is still exceeding the maximum memory. To make things even more difficult to understand, *sometimes*, completely by chance, the process is executed properly (even with a `max_queue_size` of 30!).

I verify before running my script that the memory is actually free, using `free -m` and everything looks fine. I also tried to profile my script with `memory-profiler`, although the results are quite strange:
[image]

I looks like my script is producing 54 (??????) different children and is using 1200 GB (!) of RAM. This clearly doesn't make any sense...

Am I calculating the memory usage of `fit_generator` wrong? From what I understand from the documentation, it looks like the data should be shared across workers, so the largest part of memory should be used by the queued batches. Is there anything that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you using a GPU for training or are you training on standard RAM? (This might be the memory of the model multiplied by 27) - You should also probably consider the outputs of your model as occupying memory as well. In my "little" knowledge about how much memory Keras occupies, all people who tried calculations got values far below the actual measured memory.

Comment: I'm not sure you need so many workers, a number of workers similar to your queue size should suffice, although I don't really know what `multiprocessing=True` does. When it's `false`, all workers load data in parallel and the queue goes up to the given number, sometimes + 1.

Comment: You must also consider the generator itself. Is it really memory efficient? Does it have intermediate steps that also occupy memory? Are you freeing this intermediate memory while loading the batches? ( For instance: you load an array, perform one or two operations with the array and quickly you have 3 arrays of the same size -- Even the decompressing process may be using intermediate arrays internally too)

Comment: I'm using two GPUs for the training, so no RAM is wasted for that. Multiprocessing=True enables the generator to be ran on different processes simultaneously. Since my generator is very computationally expensive, I need to have the multiprocessing setting enabled, otherwise the generator becomes a bottleneck in the traning and the GPUs starve

Comment: I think it does work simultaneously without that parameter, just have workers > 1. (Worth trying)

Comment: I tried and it is several times slower than with multiprocessing set to True